# Singletons and instance lock on properties

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

I'm about to create a class that I will use as global application configuration. This class should look like this:

```
public class GlobalConfiguration
    {    
    private static volatile GlobalConfiguration _current;
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _instanceLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public ICipher Cipher {get;set;}
    public IHasher Hasher {get;set;}
    //....

    public static GlobalConfiguration Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current == null)
            {
                _instanceLock.EnterWriteLock();
                if (_current == null) _current = new GlobalConfiguration();
                _instanceLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            return _current;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to do the following:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Current.Cipher = new AesCipher();
```

What I'm worried about now is, even though my GlobalConfiguration class is designed to be a singleton, what will happen to the Cipher property? _instanceLock is used for GlobalConfiguration class, but I am not sure on how to use it to make Cipher property thread safe as well.

Comment: How do you want the `Cipher` and `Hasher` properties to be thread safe?  Are multiple threads going to be assigning values to those properties, or are you concerned about multiple threads using the instances of those properties?

Comment: are we supposed to be able to create instance of an `interface`? assuming `ICipher` is an interface. I am just asking, not an expert on the subject.

Comment: @user1: No, provided code creates instance of `AesCipher` class that implements `ICipher` and assigns it to Cipher property of `ICipher` (interface) type.

Comment: I'm looking for thread safety on both write and read. Basically there might be some properties that will be lazy-initialized, meaning only on-demand. It does not have to be an interface, but let's say some collection that should be populated from the database. This is more question on how to make properties of singleton instance a thread safe in general.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brian Gideon's answer: remember that locking access to `Cipher` property does not restrict access to members of the instance, to which this property is set.

If you need to operate on the value of the `Cipher` property in a multi-threaded environment in a way like `GlobalConfiguration.Current.Cipher.DoSomething()`, make sure to lock access to `DoSomething()` as well (from within `AesCipher`). Or better make `AesCipher` immutable, if you can.

While it may not apply to `AesCipher` specifically, this account for "general solutions".

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the static `_instanceLock` lock to perform locking on instance members such as `Cipher`. The `_instanceLock` lock is intended to guard the creation of the singleton. Use a different lock to perform locking in the `Cipher` property. Avoid using one lock for multiple purposes. Different purposes...different locks.

Actually this is pretty standard advice in general. Using a static locking mechanism will mean that *all* instances of the same class in the same application domain will have to compete for the lock. Doing such a thing in an instance property when no static members are referenced could generate a lot of unnecessary lock contention.

Also, do you really need to use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` here? In most situations it is actually slower than a plain old `lock`. Going further, do you really need to use the double-checked locking pattern. There are times when it is appropriate and their are times when it is overkill. Take a look at [Jon Skeet's singleton implementation patterns in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) for more information.

Comment: Yeah that part is clear, that is why I'm asking for a general approach on how to lock properties. So what you're saying is if I have 10 properties on singleton, in order to have them all optimally thread safe, I should create 10 instance locks. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: @BarisaPuter: Well, no, not exactly. Using 10 different locks might be overkill, but at the very least you'll want a *static* lock to guard the singleton creation and an *instance* lock for the instance members of `GlobalConfiguration`.